# jquery r/w tooltip plugin?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Is there any jquery tooltip plugin that allows to write some values in popup bubble and save that value in DB via AJAX?!

It should also be able to display values from DB

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of jQuery plugins and jQuery / server-side-code for this.

I would recommend using the jQuery-ui Dialog plugin.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Simply populate with the content of the dialog with a form, that uses $.post() to submit the form, and then close the form once it receives an AJAX response.